# Why am I getting an "Amplify AppID (app id) not found" message?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify, aws-amplify-cli, amplifyjs

I'm trying to remotely build/deploy an app on AWS amplify and during the backend stage I get the message "Amplify appID (app id) not found", even though the app id it shows matches the one in app settings > general.

I'm not sure what could be causing this since it does actually match the app ID. In case it's relevant, I also run `amplifyPush --simple` in my backend build settings, which I had to add because of an earlier error where my aws-exports file wasn't being added.

I would greatly appreciate any help with this!

Comment: Could you do two things? Create a brand new folder, pull the backend and try to make one change. Secondly, update this question to include lots more information for us to possibly reproduce the error.